# Difficulties with constructing a surjective ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Hi I am having some trouble with this question, and I have been looking, at the proof of the first isomorphism theorem several times, but it doesn't seem to click.

The following problem is let R={a+ib$|$a,b $\in \mathbb{Q}$} be a subring of $\mathbb{C}$ Show that ring R is isomorphic to the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$

I have been trying to construct what I have mentioned, but I really don't know how to do it right. Then I have also considered to show that it is a homomorphism with congruence arithmetic and then finding the inverse. the thing is I have the tools, but I don't know how to use them.. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Define a sensible surjective map $\mathbb{Q}[x] \to R$ and show it has kernel generated by $x^2+1$.

Comment: And the kernel is the ideal in the Ring?

Comment: Kernels are always ideals (as long as your map is a ring hom).  So yes, that is the idea.  Look up the standard argument that this works over the reals to give birth to the complex numbers.

Comment: So define a function $\phi: \mathbb{Q}[x] \rightarrow R$ Where I is the ideal $x^2+1$ So I have to see what the Quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}$[x] /$(x^2+1)$ looks like.. And it looks like this $\phi: $ \mathbb{Q} [x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} $ because multiplication induces Q?

Comment: So $\phi/I$ might be isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It is definitely not $\mathbb{C}$ because your ring $R$ is countable.  It is $\mathbb{C}$-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The First Isomorphism Theorem of Rings is what you want to use in order to prove this. Recall it states the following: If $\phi: R \rightarrow R'$ is a homomorphism of rings, then $R/ker(\phi) \cong image(\phi)$.

In particular the isomorphism from $R/ker(\phi)$ onto its image is induced in a natural way by $\phi$: if $[a]$ is a coset in R/I, then it gets mapped to $\phi(a)$.

If $\phi$ is surjective, then image($\phi)= R'$. In which case $R/ker(\phi) \cong R'$.

In your case you're looking to show $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^{2} + 1 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Following the first isomorphism theorem it should be enough to find a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with the correct kernel i.e. ker$(\phi) = \langle x^{2} + 1 \rangle$. What might this be?

When defining a homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (or, any polynomial ring) one can sometimes *choose* to keep constants fixed by the homomorphism. So, in your case, you can can define a homomorphism of the required form by simplying saying: (i) constants are fixed, and (ii) where $x$ is mapped.

Finally, you must choose where $x$ is sent by this homomorphism; bearing in mind you want a particular kernel.

Comment: aha the correct kernel is i?

Comment: What you want is a homomorphism that allows you to conclude: $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^{2} + 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)$. So you want ker$(\phi) = \langle x^{2} + 1 \rangle$.